# Port Routing/DNS for individual program

Tags: linux, dns, routing, reverse-proxy

Problem: Flickr has closed its http api leaving an https only api. My favourite uploader is no longer maintained, so this change broke it.

My current solution to this is to set up a reverse proxy server to translate `http://www.flickr.com` to `https://www.flickr.com` and fix my DNS so that `www.flickr.com` traffic gets forwarded to this proxy server.

This works but obviously I don't want all my flickr traffic going to the proxy, just the traffic coming from the uploader. Can I do this?

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? eg, forward `http://www.flickr.com` straight to `https://www.flickr.com` without the proxy server.

Comment: If the server won't allow non-secure connections you are out of luck which is exactly what happen.  The application has to support those secure connections in order to function.

Comment: As I say, it works with the reverse proxy. It may also be that the libraries used work with https transparently.

Comment: What program are we talking about here, exactly?

Comment: If the uploader is open source you could just update the program to support https.  I am not aware of a way to setup a program to use a proxy when it does not explicity support said proxy.

Comment: I'm using version 2.5 of the official Flickr Uploadr, so no source code.